# Passing Boolean using JNA from Java to native C in Android

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna, android-native-library

I have seen a good answer to this question on here, however i am a little unsure on the exact implementation in my respect and the differences between passing a boolean within a structure and outside. I am working through an issue which i have asked many questions on however at this point i am working through possible errors. Within my structure i an currently passing the boolean simply as a boolean value, and outside i am passing a pointer to my boolean using IntByReference. After reading other questions and documentation i am beginning to realise that this may not be quite so straight forward, and this may well be wrong. My struct is the Matlab struct emxArray_char_T which includes a boolean canFreeData.
The official struct def:

```
struct emxArray_char_T
{
  char *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  bool canFreeData;
};
```

The documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html#mw_0cae9a4a-b74d-43f9-aae0-ed192db73d22

My Class/Structure

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "str", "size", "allocatedSize", "numDimensions", "canFreeData"})
public class emxArray_char_T extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{


    public Pointer str;
    private int numVals;
    public Pointer size;
    public int allocatedSize;
    public int numDimensions;
    public boolean canFreeData;

    //Static
    public emxArray_char_T(Pointer str, Pointer size) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
    }

    //Dynamic
    public emxArray_char_T(Pointer str, Pointer size, int allocatedSize, int numDimensions, boolean canFreeData) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
        this.allocatedSize = allocatedSize;
        this.numDimensions = numDimensions;
        this.canFreeData = canFreeData;
    }

    public emxArray_char_T() {
    }
}
```

Within this the boolean is being passed as the value which i am not sure is correct and would like advice on this?

I have another issue as i pass a boolean outside of the structure via the same initialisation function that this structure is passed in:

```
extern void Initialise(const emxArray_char_T *cStatic, const
  emxArray_char_T *cDynamic, int b_angleDeg, double
  b_offset, int b_number, int
  b_angleDeg, int b_mode, bool *status, bool
  *pStatus);
```

Passing this method is causing issues for me i need to get this right. When i map to this function i do so as:

```
    void Initialise(emxArray_char_T cStatic, emxArray_char_T cDynamic, int b_angleDeg, double
            b_offset, int b_number, int b_angleDeg, int b_mode, IntByReference status, IntByReference pStatus);
```

As mentioned there is a very good question/answer linked below, however i am struggling to understand if this is some thing i need to implement and if so how i go about it in respect to my function. I am new to JNA and am trying to learn very quickly. I appreciate all the help.

[JNA maps Java boolean to -1 integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225896/jna-maps-java-boolean-to-1-integer)

Comment: The linked answer doesn't apply in your case. It's for the case where your structure includes a 32-bit integer that is supposed to be interpreted as a boolean.   In your case, the native structure is already mapped to a boolean.

Comment: You want to map `bool *` as `BooleanByReference`.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks OK as it is except i use BooleanByReference which pretty much converts the boolean to int for reference. Thank you for helping to clarify that.

Comment: So i don't understand where i am going wrong passing data like this to the function above in C: public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    void Initialise(emxArray_char_T contentsStatic, emxArray_char_T contentsDynamic, int b_phoneAngleDeg, double b_stepCalibrationOffset, int b_initialFloorNumber, int b_initialPointingAngleDeg, int b_initialAlignmentMode, BooleanByReference mapStatus, BooleanByReference paramStatus);
} I am just getting this error as described in my other question: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) which when looked at with ADB is (rtDynamicBoundsError+203)

Comment: The full backtrace is on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864031/error-when-connecting-to-native-library-e-eglcodeccommon-goldfishaddressspaceh

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there may be a different structure definition for the "static" array as for the "dynamic" one, and that difference in structure size may be leading to stack corruption.